# is there a way to make a password in HTML

Tags: html

I am new to coding so I tried looking up how to make a password in HTML. But I ended up getting more confused and nothing that I had tried from anywhere worked or I just didn't understand it. I want to make a password that if correct will reveal a large amount of text and I have no idea what to do to create said password, so could you help me?

Comment: You can create a password input field with html `<input name="password" type="password">` but in order to verify the password you need a script that runs on the server. If you would store the correct password on the client everybody would be able to find it just by looking at the source code of your website.

Comment: Can I recommend this resource: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-web-developer-bootcamp/

Comment: Thanks but I am just testing to learn so how so I store the correct password on the client?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the user will write some password, you need js.
In html add label : password & input type=“text”, and button to send the password. Then use js to make if statements ..

1. catch the value of the password input
   2.catch the button with variable and add it
   addEventListener(click,function(){
2. write if statement like: if(password.length==4){
   alert(invalid password)
   });

Comment: So what is the js that I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for some code so I'll provide a simple demo. Keep in mind to never do something like this in production code! The password will be visible for everybody!

```js
// this is the correct password
var password = "12345";

var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit"); 
var passwordField = document.getElementById("password"); 
var hiddenText = document.getElementById("text"); 

// when submit is clicked ...
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // ... get the entered password ...
  var enteredPassword = passwordField.value;
  // ... and compare with the real password
  if (enteredPassword === password) {
    // if both passwords match then show the hidden text
    hiddenText.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="password" type="password">
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>

<p id="text" style="display: none;">This is the hidden text!!!</p>
```

Comment: I tried to use it and it wont work I am using visual code studio if that has anything to do with it

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that. Make sure that you include the script tag (`<script>...</script>` **after** the input elements (just insert the script before the closing `</body>` tag) otherwise it won't work.